# SQL Error 6304 - XML parsing: An unexpected error has occurred in the XML parser

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm running SQL Server 2019 and not sure if it's related to this, but on SQL Server 2014 if I create a table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
  FieldA smallint NOT NULL,
  FieldB xml NOT NULL
)
```

And run this query

```
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES(1, '<Test1>
<to>TEST</to>
</Test1>');
```

Everything goes smoothly, but if I create the same table on a different database on SQL 2019 and run the same query to insert that row I get an XML parsing error, which I really can't get to the bottom of it..

Comment: Your code works for me on SQL Server 2019.  What compatability level is the database set to where you are getting an error?

Comment: Runs fine in dbfiddle even on SQL Server 2014, see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=37768e7dbbcc3c19d9e272f253e4ffce What build number is this server `select @@version`? Is this happening even on a brand new table in that DB?

Comment: @squillman We should probably get this over to [dba.se]

Comment: @Charlieface that returns "Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23...." .

Comment: @squillman It's set to 150, I've tried changing it and playing around with it, but it didn't solve the issue

Comment: I strongly suggest you upgrade to the latest build, which is CU13. Are there triggers on the target table, any check constraints or computed columns? Is there anything else unusual about the table?

Comment: Yeah, this sounds like a server instance issue, voting to move to dba.se

Comment: Can you provide the full error text that you're encountering? Those scripts work fine on a 2019 instance I have, and on db<>fiddle.

Comment: What collation is set on the database where this is failing?